# Google API - URL Shortener with PHP

Tags: php, url, curl, qr-code

My code is below. The URL shortening service works, but it doesn't when I insert my `$POST`. Does anyone know how to fix this my looking at the code?

```
// This is the URL you want to shorten
$longUrl = 'http://www.mysite.com/XXXXX/XX/$_POST['qrname']';

// Get API key from : http://code.google.com/apis/console/
$apiKey = 'MyAPIKey';

$postData = array('longUrl' => $longUrl, 'key' => $apiKey);
$jsonData = json_encode($postData);

$curlObj = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url');
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

$response = curl_exec($curlObj);

// Change the response json string to object
$json = json_decode($response);

curl_close($curlObj);

echo 'Shortened URL is: '.$json->id;
```

Comment: Remove or comment echo 'Shortened URL is: '.$json->id; after check . ! It works .

Comment: I don't know where you find this code in the API doc, but thanks !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try as below

`$longUrl = 'http://www.mysite.com/XXXXX/XX/'.$_POST['qrname'];`

The above will work.

Comment: Your problem is nothing about cURL, it's about concatenating variables and string in PHP, see http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php

Comment: May I know why I can't use OP's Php code and shorten the url? It return me error message `domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg", "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."` ? I'd check my Http Referrer, Quota, everything looks good....

Answer (score 7):

you are passing the php variable between the single quotes so it will not be parsed.
pass it between double quotes like

```
$longUrl = "http://www.mysite.com/XXXXX/XX/$_POST['qrname']";
```

OR concatinate like this

```
$longUrl = 'http://www.mysite.com/XXXXX/XX/'.$_POST['qrname'];
```

Comment: I prefer this answer over Hackableweb's as it does not just solve the problem, but also tells the OP, ***why***!

Answer (score 7):

```
$longUrl = "http://www.xxxxxxx.com";
    $postData = array('longUrl' => $longUrl);
    $jsonData = json_encode($postData);

    //4
    $curlObj = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=yourappkey');
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);

    //5
    $response = curl_exec($curlObj);

    $json = json_decode($response);
//       echo "<pre>";
//    print_r($json);exit;
    //6
    curl_close($curlObj);

    //7
    if(isset($json->error)){
        echo $json->error->message;
    }else{
        echo $json->id;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You have a key, but you are not using it correctly

You should append it to the url, don't send the key in the post

```
https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key='.$apiKey
```

Please check https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/insert

Comment: This solved it for me, some of the existing documentation is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough reputation points yet to comment, but I got this working fine by replacing the line:

```
echo 'Shortened URL is: '.$json->id;
```

with:

```
$shortLink = get_object_vars($json);
echo "Shortened URL is: ".$shortLink['id'];
```

It could be just my php installation, but the original line kept throwing a 500 Internal Error for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
//URL Shortening Functions( Just copy & paste below code in your application)
function short_url($longUrl){
        $apiKey = '******************'; // put your GOOGLE API SHORTENING KEY 
        $postData = array('longUrl' => $longUrl, 'key' => $apiKey);
        $curlObj = curl_init();
        $jsonData = json_encode($postData);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key='.$postData['key']);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json'));
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
        $response = curl_exec($curlObj);
        $json = json_decode($response);
        curl_close($curlObj);
        if(isset($json->error) || $json == null){
             return $longUrl; // retrun same url in case of error or null response
        }else{
            return $json->id; // return shorted url
        }
    }
// use this function here
$longUrl = 'https://www.w3schools.com/';
echo short_url($longUrl); // print short url

// If you want to return short url to long url use below function
function long_url($shortUrl){
        $apiKey = '***********'; // put your GOOGLE API SHORTENING Key
        $params = array('shortUrl' => $shortUrl, 'key' => $apiKey,'projection' => "ANALYTICS_CLICKS");
        $final_url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?'.http_build_query($params);
        $curlObj = curl_init($final_url);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type:application/json'));
        $response = curl_exec($curlObj);
        $json = json_decode($response);
        curl_close($curlObj);
        if(isset($json->error) || $json == null){
            return $shortUrl;
        }else{
            return $json->longUrl;
        }
    }
//Function Use here
echo "<br>"; // For next line
$shortUrl = ''; // put the short url generated from above function
echo long_url($shortUrl); // get long url
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. I is working for me.

```
$api_key = 'YOUR_KEY';
$request_data = array(
    'longUrl' => 'YOUR_LONG_URL'
);

$curl_obj = curl_init(sprintf('%s/url?key=%s', 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1', $api_key));
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($request_data));
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$response = curl_exec($curl_obj);
$json = json_decode($response);
curl_close($curl_obj);

var_dump($json);
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `$longUrl = 'http://www.example.com/XXXXX/XX/$_POST['qrname']';`

with the following

`$longUrl = 'http://www.example.com/XXXXX/XX/{$_POST['qrname']}';`