# why i am getting forbidden error in googleurl shotner api?

Tags: php, google-url-shortener

why i am getting forbidden error my code is-

```
$api_key="my-api-key";
    $json='{
            "longUrl": "honortraders-2.myshopify.com/admin"

            }';


$url="https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?&key=".$api_key;

                                $curl = curl_init();
                                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'));
                                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
                                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
                                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
                                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                                    $response = curl_exec ($curl);
                                    curl_close ($curl); 
                                    echo $response;*i am trying to use google urlshortner api but i am getting forbidden error*
```

Comment: Might help this question in your case. [Google API - URL Shortener with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066919/google-api-url-shortener-with-php)

Comment: No i am not getting help from. Google API - URL Shortener with PHP

Comment: Can you add your error in this question?

Comment: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden", "message": "Forbidden" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Forbidden" } }

Comment: I have found that google urlshortner is not useful for new user who want to create new short url.

For developers

> Starting May 30, 2018, only projects that have accessed URL Shortener APIs before today can create short links. To create new short links, we recommend FDL APIs. FDL short links will automatically detect the user's platform and send the user to either the web or your app, as appropriate.